# Jupyter Notebook version 5.7.5 has been installed but I get error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[Installed Jupyter 5.7.5 and when I type 
jupyter notebook --version
5.7.5
is displayed but later when I type
jupyter notebook
I get the following error and tried all posssible solutions listed on StackOVerflow website but could not fix it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksTQ7.png)

Comment: I have done a pip install not anaconda install.

Answer (score 0):

I see now that the problem is that you're using Python 3.8, following the previous threads try the following:

1. Locate and open the asyncio.py file. In my case it's in C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py
2. After the lineimport asyncio add the following:

```html
import sys

if platform == "win32":               
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

Comment: I updated to version 6.0.2 now but still the same error persists :(

Comment: try running: pip3 uninstall jupyter and then pip3 install jupyter. or just pip in case you run into problems

Comment: Tried this but same issue :(

Comment: original solution from @gdlmx from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805213