# Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.8 - NotImplementedError

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, tornado

Upgraded recently to Python 3.8, and installed `jupyter`. However, when trying to run `jupyter notebook` getting the following error:

```
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 99, in add_handler
    self.asyncio_loop.add_reader(fd, self._handle_events, fd, IOLoop.READ)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 501, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

I know Python 3.8 on windows switched to `ProactorEventLoop` by default, so I suspect it is related to this.

Jupyter does not support Python 3.8 at the moment? Is there a work around?

Comment: Python 3.8 is very fresh so better go back to 3.7 and wait some time till it will be better tested and modules will be create specially for 3.8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter notebook cannot start with python 3.8 in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805213/jupyter-notebook-cannot-start-with-python-3-8-in-windows-10)

Comment: still broken in 3.8.1 (released today).

Comment: This is now fixed in version 6.0.3 of jupyter notebook. Upgrade with `pip install notebook --upgrade`

Answer (score 201, accepted):

**EDIT**

This issue exists in older versions of Jupyter Notebook and was fixed in version **6.0.3** (released 2020-01-21).  To upgrade to the latest version run:

```
pip install notebook --upgrade
```

---

<strike>Following on this issue through GitHub, it seems the problem is related to the `tornado` server that jupyter uses.</strike>

For those that can't wait for an official fix, I was able to get it working by editing the file `tornado/platform/asyncio.py`, by adding:

```
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

After the main imports.

I expect an official fix for this soon, however.

Comment: Do not expect a fix from Tornado team: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2608

Comment: if you were looking for asyncio.py, take a look at "C:\Python3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\platform"

Comment: Thanks! If you're using a conda env, Make sure to change the version in the env and not only the global one. Second, make sure you add this change after the `import asyncio` statement :)

Comment: This fixed it for me. In particular:
1. You can get the file location from the stack trace if you run: jupyter -m notebook
2. On my system the file is located here: C:\Users\_NAME_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py

Comment: This worked for me. If you use virtualenv, this fix needs be applied only to your environment in ENV-DIRECTORY\Lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py

Comment: This didn't work for me January 2020, Python3.8 but Mirwise Khan's answer below did

Comment: I have the latest and it is not fixed.

Comment: the 'notebook --upgrade' might fix Jupyter Notebook; however, the tornado/asyncio modification for windows platform is still needed e.g. to [run the latest version of Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557238/spyder-ide-fails-to-start-on-windows-10-with-python-3-8), so you might want to keep the workaround in the answer.

Comment: I tried the notebook upgrade, and even delete it and reinstall, but I still got the problem. I finally used the fix in the `tornado\platform\asyncio.py`.

Comment: may I ask how to update python version **from** 3.7.7 **to** 3.8 via **conda** command or manually within anaconda app on macOS?

Comment: Tornado 6.0.4,  Note that it is still necessary to use asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy()) for this platform/version.    https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v6.0.4.html#general-changes

Comment: Upgrading only jupyter didn't do it for me. I also had to update `ipykernel` seperately.

Comment: Updating notebook did not work in my case, inserting the code block solved it instead.

Answer (score 45):

Revising the answer in 2019

Change the end part of the file
`C:\Users\{USER-NAME}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\asyncio\__init__.py`

From

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':  # pragma: no cover
    from .windows_events import *
    __all__ += windows_events.__all__
else:
    from .unix_events import *  # pragma: no cover
    __all__ += unix_events.__all__
```

To

```
import asyncio

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    from .windows_events import *
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    __all__ += windows_events.__all__
else:
    from .unix_events import *  # pragma: no cover
    __all__ += unix_events.__all__
```

Comment: Both the question and accepted answer were from October 2019 and the solution worked for me

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me. this did. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too, python 3.8 in jan 2020

Comment: I would **not** go and alter Python's standard library source code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters make a copy of the file somewhere, try the above solution, if it works > well n good, otherwise just replace the file with old one >> Kinda Win-Win situation

Comment: You can do this **anywhere else**, like in [`site.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html).

Comment: I was having the same issue using Pycharm with Python38 (trying to start localhost:8521 and getting the NotImplementedError) and this solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had to reinstall asyncio

```
pip install asyncio --upgrade
```

And upgrade the kernel package

```
pip install ipykernel --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the python version from 3.9 to 3.7. (Windows).