# Process to install JupyterLab using Miniconda

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab

I am trying to get jupyterlab working using an environment handled by miniconda. However, starting from a fresh environment using python 3.8.0 and simply doing

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

First lead me to an asyncio related error. I was able to solve it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422817/jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-8-notimplementederror) answer.

Now I am facing a DLL import error :

```
File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

And I can't solve this. I tried using python 3.6.0 instead of 3.8.0. This did not work.

Any idea ? I am using Windows 10 build 1809 64 bits system.

Comment: Does it work with pip ?

Comment: can't even install with pip which seems logical it is not advised to install with pip using conda

Comment: I meant outside of the conda environment, iirc for windows in order to use conda you need the Anaconda prompt