# Jupyter install ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I type the following in the the windows command prompt: pip install jupyterlab

I received the following error:

```
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0mx8si2m\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0mx8si2m\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0mx8si2m\pywinpty\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0mx8si2m\pywinpty\
    Complete output (166 lines):
    Compiling C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Plex\Scanners.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Plex\Actions.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\FusedNode.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Tempita\_tempita.py because it changed.
    [1/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.py
    [2/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\FusedNode.py
    [3/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py
    [4/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py
    [5/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Plex\Actions.py
    [6/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Plex\Scanners.py
    [7/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx
    [8/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Tempita\_tempita.py
    Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
    warning: no files found matching 'Doc\*'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Utility'
    warning: no files found matching 'pyximport\README'
    Scanners.c
       Creating library build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Plex\Scanners.cp38-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Plex\Scanners.cp38-win32.exp
    Generating code
    Finished generating code
    LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 534, in link
        self.spawn([self.linker] + ld_args)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 557, in spawn
        return super().spawn(cmd)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 910, in spawn
        spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 38, in spawn
        _spawn_nt(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 80, in _spawn_nt
        raise DistutilsExecError(
    distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
        cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
        self.run_command(cmdname)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
        self.build()
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 84, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 205, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 550, in build_extension
        self.compiler.link_shared_object(
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 713, in link_shared_object
        self.link(CCompiler.SHARED_OBJECT, objects,
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 537, in link
        raise LinkError(msg)
    distutils.errors.LinkError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\setup.py", line 228, in 
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
        raise
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rvu4jwr1\Cython-0.29.14\setup.py", line 228, in 
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0mx8si2m\pywinpty\setup.py", line 68, in 
        setup(
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1146, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Try reverting back to python 3.7, you will have trouble installing many common packages on python 3.8 right now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.8 - NotImplementedError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422817/jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-8-notimplementederror)

Answer (score 0):

simply follow this to install jupyter in windows :-

1nd - Go to file manager and find python folder (like:-*python*,*python37*,*python39* etc...) may be it's in (***C:\Python39***) or (***C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Programs\python39***) .

2rd - in python folder open Scripts folder (Ex:- ***C:.....\python39\Scripts***) and copy this path.

3rd - 'run cmd as administrator' and past above path using cd (like:- cd ***C:.....\python39\Scripts***)

4th - now simply use jupyter install command (like :-

> pip install jupyterlab

)