# jupyter-notebook open error:NotImplementedError

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am a Windows user, and I have installed Python 3.8 on my computer. In order to use Jupyter notebooks. I already installed ipython and pandas. After entering the command jupyter notebook on the command-line, my browser doesn't open jupyter notebook, instead I get the follow error message,I also don't know what have error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F38O.png)

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422817/jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-8-notimplementederror

Comment: 1Yeah!Thank you! This web can slove my problems.Best wish to you!