# Getting NotImplementedError with Jupyter Notebook and Python3.8

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, python-3.8

I have installed Jupyter Notebook via the command prompt using

```
pip install jupyter
```

When I am running it on my computer, it does not run. This is the error:

[image: error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.8 - NotImplementedError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422817/jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-8-notimplementederror)

Answer (score 0):

It is an related to Python 3.8.

Either downgrade the version or follow these related threads in Github:

- https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4526
- https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6487