# Making reprexpy work with PyCharm and Python 3.9

Tags: python, pycharm, reprex

I am new to Python and PyCharm. I managed to install the package `reprexpy` (see a decription [here](https://pypi.org/project/reprexpy/#:%7E:text=reprexpy%20is%20a%20Python%20package,of%20the%20R%20package%20reprex.)) but when I run it I get the following error:

```
from reprexpy import reprex
reprex()
Rendering reprex...
Traceback (most recent call last):
(...)
  packages\zmq\asyncio.py", line 56, in _init_io_state
    self.io_loop.add_reader(self._fd, lambda: self._handle_events(0, 0))
  File "C:\Users\Serena\anaconda3\envs\python prep\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 504, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

I would really like to make this work so I can create reproducible examples in Python. I am using Python 3.9 on the latest version of PyCharm (2021.1.1 Pro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work. First, referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422817/jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-8-notimplementederror), I imported asyncio from the terminal:

```
 pip install asyncio --upgrade
```

That took two or three attempts. Then I changed the `__init__.py` file following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59512181/5535152). Finally restarted PyCharm and now `reprex()` is working:

```py
range(4)
#> range(0, 4)
for i in range(4):
    print(i)
#> 0
#> 1
#> 2
#> 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprexpy package](https://github.com/crew102/reprexpy)</sup>

Comment: Hi Emy, you may also need to install the latest version of reprexpy, as I recently fixed a few issues with it that may have been leading to unexpected behavior.