# Spyder IDE fails to start on Windows 10 with Python 3.8

Tags: windows-10, tornado, spyder, pywin32, python-3.8

## Note: this issue is fixed in Spyder 4.1.3!

---

(original question) checking out Python 3.8 (x64) on Windows 10, I got into trouble when trying to setup `Spyder`. Note: the issue was reproducible with a fresh Python installation on a clean Windows-10 system. However, no such issues on Linux (tested on debian / Mint19.x).

At first, everything went smooth during installation via `pip install spyder`.

---

**error #1:** `pywin32`

After starting `Spyder`, it said in the IPython console window:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1572, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle)
File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()
File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 470, in write_connection_file
self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,
File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 141, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 424, in secure_write
win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 359, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I was able to fix the import error by running `pywin32_postinstall.py -install` from the scripts folder (from a `cmd` prompt with elevated rights). That copies `pythoncom38.dll` and `pywintypes38.dll` from `\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32` to `\windows\system32`, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238403/import-win32api-error-in-python-2-6) - however, I'd suggest to **not modify** system folders and use the option I put in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58682830/10197418) below.

---

**error #2:** `tornado`

However, now `Spyder` just freezes at the loading screen (logo displayed, saying something like "initializing main window")!

cloning the dev version of Spyder from https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder.git and running it via `python bootstrap.py --debug` reveals the cause of the freeze:

```
2019-11-03 17:39:53,261 [ERROR] [tornado.application] -> Exception in callback functools.partial(<function ThreadedZMQSocketChannel.__init__.<locals>.setup_stream at 0x0000015E00B758B0>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\threaded.py", line 48, in setup_stream
    self.stream = zmqstream.ZMQStream(self.socket, self.ioloop)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 127, in __init__
    self._init_io_state()
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 546, in _init_io_state
    self.io_loop.add_handler(self.socket, self._handle_events, self.io_loop.READ)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 99, in add_handler
    self.asyncio_loop.add_reader(fd, self._handle_events, fd, IOLoop.READ)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 501, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

...so it seems the import error caused by the Python 3.8 version of `pywin32` is only one issue. There's also a problem related to `tornado` IO (web server), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805213/jupyter-notebook-cannot-start-with-python-3-8-in-windows-10) / [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54608421/how-to-fix-notimplementederror-when-trying-to-run-hydrogen-in-atom).

> last checked with Python 3.8.2 (AMD64), Spyder 4.1.1. Please note that I am ***not*** using Anaconda. Use either `conda` ***or*** `pip`, not both.

Comment: try to do a proper remove of the spyder version with some external cleaning tools and install it again

Comment: @PV8: what do you mean by *cleaning tools*? can you suggest any?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631512/pywin32-and-python-3-8-0/58632354#58632354

Comment: @CristiFati: thanks for your comment, that looks promising! I'll check it out as soon as I find the time

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## ***Spyder 4.1.3 Update: The issue is fixed!***

(Tested on Python 3.8.3rc1, tornado 6.0.4)

If you come here still experiencing similar startup issues with Spyder: the first thing to try I'd suggest ***upgrade to Spyder version >= 4.1.3***.

---

***older version of this answer***

**workaround, tornado issue:**

Modify the file `...\Python38...\Lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py`;
add

```py
import sys
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

after the other import statements. Source: [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422817/jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-8-notimplementederror/58430041#58430041) and also linked [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4613#issuecomment-548992047). If I get [this](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2608) post on the `tornado` repo right, this is likely to be a pretty permanent workaround.

---

if also needed - **workaround, pywin32 issue:**

Modify the file `...\Python38\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\path.py`;
add a line

```py
import pywintypes
```

*before* `import win32api` in line 359. This modification is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631512/pywin32-and-python-3-8-0/58632354#58632354) post.

Comment: Yessssssssssss!

Comment: This is finally fixed in our 4.1.3 version, released yesterday. Could you update your answer accordingly?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba: yes, I was very happy to find that out yesterday, after having Spyder installed on a fresh Win10!

Comment: is there a way to upgrade python 3.7 to 3.8 with conda command or to handle it through anaconda navigator?